# Telegram Bot работает только у меня

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Суть: у меня бот работает, у других нет.
Сам бот: michael_kot_bot
Команды:
/help
/setting
В Netbrans прога **запущена**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете запустить сейчас?

Comment: да, работает для Вас)

Comment: Хм, да, не откликается на команды.

Comment: у друзей тоже самое(

Comment: есть такой нюанс: я не использую maven, может ли быть ошибка из-за этого?

Comment: код нужен? там все понятно, брал отсюда: https://geekbrains.ru/events/840

Comment: до 35 минуты дошел

Comment: в видео, у него, как и у меня, тоже работает

Comment: @МишаКотор попробуйте с другого пк с вашего аккаунта. Я подозреваю, что он только у вас работает, т.к. вы его создавали, т.е. вы админ. Но не понятно, из-за чего это.

Comment: P.S. Теоретически Maven не должен влиять, но я не знаю, как у вас написан код. Попробуйе, сделайте как [в статье на JR](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/504-sozdanie-telegram-bota-na-java-ot-idei-do-deploja)

Comment: тут же через Maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, всем спасибо за помощь! Знаете в чем была проблема?
Первый раз я запустил его. **Его надо остановить**. После этого его смогли запускать все остальные. Не претендую на лучшее решение, но мне оно помогло.